# selenium flashscore scrape tennis

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Good day! I'm trying to scrape info about matches from this site https://www.flashscore.com/player/nadal-rafael/xUwlUnRK/results/
with code:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--headless")

    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)


    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options = options, firefox_profile=profile)
    driver.implicitly_wait(40)

    driver.get('https://www.flashscore.com/player/nadal-rafael/xUwlUnRK/results/')

    src = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "html.parser")

    table = soup.prettify()

    f = open('text.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    f.write(table)
    f.close()

    driver.close()
```

But finally all text contains matches inside tag with id="fs-results_s" disappear

```
<div class="fs-passive fs-table tournament-page" id="fs-results_s">
          </div>
```

. I tried using Chrome, but that doesn't help.
What can be the error?

Comment: Might be a problem with BeautifulSoup? Check your pagesource before prettify. I used c# with chrome driver: driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.flashscore.com/player/nadal-rafael/xUwlUnRK/results/"); string Temp = driver.PageSource; This string contains all text inside tag with id="fs-results_s".

Comment: thanks for help, but this doesn't help

Comment: solve by adding wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Singles")))